# Is it needed to activate Google Cloud first to use IdP functionality of Google?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, idp, anypoint-platform

I'm trying to use Google as my IdP (OIDC) for Anypoint Platform, I was able to get into the google login site using my Anypoint Platform domain link, however when I logged in to my Google Account it does not direct to the Anypoint Platform site, it only shows "The request could not be processed" page, so I was thinking maybe it is because I have not yet activated the Google Cloud. Is the activation of google cloud required to use the Idp functionality? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try [this documentation article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?ref_topic=7559288&hl=en)? Please, ypdate your answer with more details on what have you tried so far.

Comment: It maybe that the configuration for SSO in Anypoint Platform is not correct to complete the redirection, or the configuration in Google is not correct. It is very difficult to understand without detailed information.